# Google Maps - Disable map tiles and show only polygon shapes

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Working with Google Maps V3 Api. This is a strange request, but i wondered if its possible to draw polygon shapes on the map canvas using LAT and LONG, but disable/hide the the map tiles within the canvas. So in short, id like to show JUST the shapes that are drawn on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per google maps docs you can do this when you initialize your map:

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
          zoom: 12,
          styles: [
            {elementType: 'all', stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
          ]
        });
```

This applies a custom style that hides everything on the map. You could then apply a style to your polygons to make them appear.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: A better option if you are doing highly custom stuff and want to have full customizablility would be to try out leaflet.js :)